# Sentence structure with "une fois" in French seems to be missing a verb, as compared with English construction

Tags: grammaire, syntaxe, constructions, comparaison-de-langues

There is a sentence structure that is used in French that I continue to be challenged with. Can someone explain what is going on or what the rule is in French?

Here is the original sentence:

- Une fois la préparation des paiements terminée, chaque prestation le composant fait l’objet d’une mise à jour de ses données au dépôt Rentes.

Which for me translates to the nonsensical sentence in English:

- Once the preparation of the payments terminated, each benefit the component makes the object of an update of its data in the Rentes depot.

To my anglophone mind, there appears to be a verb missing. For example, I would tend to think of writing the sentence this way:

- Une fois la préparation des paiements est terminée, chaque prestation du composant fait l’objet d’une mise à jour de ses données au dépôt Rentes.

Which to me makes more (but perhaps not perfect) sense in English as:

- Once the preparation of the payments is terminated, each benefit of the component makes the object of an update of its data in the Rentes depot.

I note that both sentences are correct according to Antidote. My francophone friend assures me that the first is correct and the second, though acceptable by Antidote, is not really correct in their mind.

Do they mean the same thing? If not, what is the difference?

If so, what rule in French allows the verb "est" to be removed and the "de" of "du" to be not specified?

Or perhaps more general, can someone provide the parsing of this sentence structure in French to help me understand where the subject is, the verb, and the object?

Comment: Can you post what is written before the original sentence or provide a link to that text?

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is possibly incorrect and fooled you. It probably should have used *la composant*, although we would need more context to be sure. With a feminine or a plural, you probably wouldn't have confused the pronoun/verb *le/la/les composant* (composing it, *it* being the *preparation*) with the article/noun *le composant* (the component):

> *...chaque prestation **la composant** fait l’objet...*

> ...each benefit **composing it (i.e. composing the preparation)** makes...

Comment: J'aurais dit "les composant", car selon moi les prestations font probablement référence aux paiements et non à la préparation de ceux-ci. Peut-être que je me trompe ! :)

Comment: @Reyedy C'est vrai, oui. "composant la préparation des paiements", ça ne veut pas dire grand chose... L'antécédent n'est pas clair. L'auteur a peut-être aussi mis le pronom au singulier parce qu'il pensait à *paiement* au singulier, donc *composant le paiement*. C'est en fait ce que j'avais compris lors de ma première réponse. De toute façon, c'est relativement accessoire, l'essentiel est de faire comprendre à l'OP qu'il ne s'agit pas d'un article suivi d'un nom commun mais d'un pronom suivi d'un verbe.

Comment: Tout à fait d'accord.

Comment: Dans les commentaires des deux autres réponse, un essai, parfois contesté, envisage le *la* comme probable. À vous de voir :-)

Comment: @Personne Bienheureux qui pourra nous le dire... mais il n'a plus remis les pieds ici depuis sa question :-(

Comment: Cela ressemble un peu à l'académisme contre Molière

Comment: Tu as choisi ton camp ? ;-)

Comment: L'ambiguïté (la polysémie pour les gens de lettres écrites) contre la musique des mots (l'oralité des comédiens) est proche de la physique quantique, la solution ne nous appartient pas, si nous l'imposons par la lettre, le calcul, le mental nous détruisons ce que nous ignorons, si nous le suggérons dans l'oralité, chacun y trouvera son compte… bigre un monde sans certitude existe ? et qu'en dit la Vie ?

Comment: En fait il n'y a pas de choix, « Tout ce qui n'est pas pour moi est contre moi » a fait suffisamment de dégâts … pas facile de découvrir que le Diable en personne se cache dans chaque jugement de valeur basé sur une formulation hasardeuse, incomplète ou biaisée … vaste programme qui ne s'écrit certainement pas en C++ ou en Java — Fin de mes commentaires relatifs à cette question et aux réponses effectuées  :-)

Comment: @Personne ☯☯☯☯☯☯☯☯

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is something like a latin absolute ablative. An equivalent form could be: une fois que la présentation des paiements est terminée, ...

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ablatif_absolu?wprov=sfti1

I also think that the correct pronoun is “les” and not “le”

Comment: All things [being] considered, with your answer [being] the only one so far to address both parts of OP's question, the part actually presented in the question's title [being] included, I think it [is] deserving of my +1!

Comment: La réécriture de la première partie de la phrase n'empêche pas d'essayer : « chaque prestation **la** composant fait l’objet d’une mise à jour de ses données au dépôt Rente » → « chaque prestation  composant **cette préparation** fait l’objet d’une mise à jour de ses données au dépôt Rente ». Est-ce que la notion d'ablatif absolu accepterait une 'lourdeur' telle « chaque prestation  composant **les paiements de cette préparation** fait l’objet d’une mise à jour de ses données au dépôt Rente » est concevable ?

Comment: @PapaPoule Bien vu. J'avais loupé le problème que posait à l'OP la première partie. +1 aussi alors !

Answer (score 1):

In itself this sentence is not correct ; the pronoun « le » is masculine singular and there is no word in it that is masculine singular and that could be referred to by this pronoun, not « préparation », not « paiements » ; therefore, either the pronoun is erroneous and most likely it is « les », or there is something else that is being mentioned before this sentence and that is what the pronoun refers to. In case this latter possibility is not verifiable, then, most likely what is being referred to is « paiements », which is why I supposed above that « les  » was the pronoun needed. (Les paiements sont composés de prestations.)

- Une fois la préparation des paiements terminée, chaque prestation **les** composant fait l’objet d’une mise à jour de ses données au dépôt Rentes.

*In other words,  this sentence is equivalent to the following.*

- Une fois la préparation des paiements terminée, chaque prestation  composant **les paiements** fait l’objet d’une mise à jour de ses données au dépôt Rentes.

Your second sentence is not correct.

Comment: Je n'ai pas moinssoyé, mais il y a une erreur d'oreille (ce que l'oreille entend et ce que le cerveau en déduit) : comment argumenter sur *les paiements* alors que l'on peut valider la même action sans eux :  « Une fois la préparation … terminée, chaque prestation ***les ?*** composant fait l’objet … », d'autant plus que chaque préparation fait l'objet d'une mise à jour des *prestations*.

Comment: @Personne   Il existe en effet la possibilité que le pronom en question soit "la" et alors  les prestations composent la préparation  ; « prestation » n'est plus qu'un synonyme pour « paiements, ce qui convient assez bien puisque les deux mots sont au pluriel. Seulement, le sens de « préparation » qui convient est celui-ci : « (TLFi) b) **Choisir une chose, rassembler un certain nombre de choses nécessaires à une opération à venir et les tenir prêtes.** Préparer sa monnaie, son bulletin de vote. » ; de plus, des deux choix de sens pour « préparation » ((TLFi) Action de préparer (1/3)

Comment: @Personne  quelque chose ; résultat de cette action.), il n'est pas question de considérer que c'est le second ; il ne s'agit pas du résultat mais de l'action. Pourquoi ? Tout simplement parce que l'on ne termine pas une chose finie… Donc en fin de compte nous sommes amenés à parler des prestations d'une action, celle de faire des relevés des calcul et des assignations. C'est du nonsens le plus complet et donc le représenté est bien « paiements » à mon avis et non pas « préparation », ce qui a d'autant plus de sens que un paiement donné, en particulier dans le cas d'un employé, (2/3)

Comment: @Personne qui ne jouit pas nécessairement des mêmes avantages qu'un autre, peut bénéficier de prestations variés constituant son paiement. Mais cette dernière constatation n'est que conjecture puisque nous ne connaissons pas la nature de ces paiements. (3/3)

Comment: Par les sens proches de « **Préparation** : (TLFi) b) Choisir une chose, rassembler un certain nombre de choses nécessaires à une opération à venir et les tenir prêtes. » et de « **Composer** : (CNRTL : I.− [L'idée dominante est celle de mettre ensemble] A : … Former un tout par assemblage ou combinaison de divers éléments. », *mon oreille* en déduit ***la***. Bien qu'ayant travaillé dans des services liés à la finance et au droit, j'ai du mal à entrer dans votre raisonnement, sans pour autant porter un jugement sur sa valeur. P.S. : Pour ne pas retomber dans les problèmes que vous avez connu,

Comment: … évitez/éliminez l'envie d'avoir raison, d'avoir le dernier mot *(… C'est du non-sens le plus complet et …)* sur un argumentaire aussi incertain.

Comment: @Personne Évitez de me prêter des sentiments qui ne sont pas les miens et expliquez vous plutôt, si vous le pouvez.

Comment: Je vous laisse à votre raison, à vos certitudes et me réfugie dans le silence.

Comment: @Personne Comment voulez-vous que je ne sois pas laissé à mes raisons , pour la plupart, si personne n'est capable de me montrer rationnellement qu'elles ne sont pas bien fondées ; simplement me dire « Ça ne vaut rien. » est facile à faire et nombreux sont ceux qui me critiquent de cette façon, cependant, nombreux aussi sont ceux qui ne partagent pas leur avis ou qui ont une explication sensée lorsqu'ils apposent un « -1 ».

Comment: *L'oreille* n'est pas rationnelle, elle est intuitive et spontanée, on apprend sa langue maternelle *à l'oreille*, elle est passive et intimement liée à la conscience, avec l'éducation, elle est subordonnée à la rationalité. La Raison donne-t-elle pour autant *le devoir* d'écarter, de rejeter, de dénier tout ce qu'elle ne peut appréhender, et de porter un jugement sans appel sur ce qui ne lui est pas accessible, ce qu'elle ne peut justifier ou formater ? Au fond, doit-elle rejeter l'Autre en rejetant/détruisant ses arguments et surtout son point de vue quand il ne corrobore pas le seul …

Comment: … auquel elle a eu accès ? C'est peut-être là, la source principale des -1 et des autres problèmes. Pour ma part je retourne au silence et forclos mes commentaires.